# HSQLDB + SQuirreL: reading data by block

Tags: hsqldb, squirrel-sql

I'm running an instance of HSQLDB from inside a Java class: an instance of `org.hsqldb.Server` is initialized and set to be only in memory, no other configuration; then, it's used filling it with data accessible from outside the running jvm.

Using SQuirreL set to "Read on, Block size", I connect to HSQLDB server and query for data: it seems like all returning rows from the query are loaded in client memory and then displayed by block size. Instead, using Oracle (by example) I see the client downloading only displayed rows, others are downloaded only when the list is scrolled down. Is it possible to force HSQLDB client to act in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The query is performed using a java.sql.Statement object. This has a `setFetchSize(n)` method that indicates the number of rows that are fetched at one time. HSQLDB supports this when it is used in Server mode. It returns the rows in chunks containing the indicated fetch size.

The application program, in this case SQuirrel, should explicitly call `setFetchSize(n)` on the Statement object.